# Error getting User data from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

The login flow is working, I get a valid access token and everything. But when I retrieve the user data, I only get the name and userID. No email or other info from the public profile.

If I run a `/me/permissions` it returns `granted` on both email and public_profile. If I use facebook's Debug Tool with the access token it tells me the correct scope: email,public_profile.

So why am I not being able to get the data? I can't finish the signup process without it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because API v2.4. Go read the changelog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Graph API 2.4, it no more returns several fields, you should explicitly ask for fields you want. See [Graph API Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Please read [Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4), especially this part about [choosing fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fields)